# Quarter is to quartile as half is to...?

Tags: distributions, median

Is there one word to describe the sections of data on either side of the median? I'd guess "half", but it seems like there ought be something better...

Comment: Strictly speaking, isn't quarter to quartile as half is to median? The dictionary definition of eg upper quartile is the cutoff value rather than the set formed by the top 25% of data. (Edit: I have posted almost simultaneously with @Tim, who makes the same point.)

Comment: I'd definitely use 'half'. Consider "lower half" vs "upper half" or "left half" vs "right half"

Comment: Your title is confusing. It seems to me you are looking for a word like "half", so wouldn't it make more sense to ask "quartile is to quarter as median is to ...?"

Comment: Use of the term "quantile" to describe a range and not a value should probably be considered an abuse of the term

Comment: In addition to @Glen_b's suggestions, "top half" and "bottom half" are crystal clear to me.  Referencing the median is also helpful in creating a clear visual.

Comment: But don't people commonly also refer to the 'third quartile' as being the group of datapoints with values between 50%-75% of the distribution? So depending on context, quartile could mean either just the value, or the group. @ssdecontrol - for better or worse, seems that usage is firmly-established.

Comment: @smci absolutely. my unfounded suspicion is that that was the _original_ usage, and the "cut point" meaning came later when statisticians needed a more concise way to say "the cutoff of the 40th percentile"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

...as half to median. "Quarter" and "half" are names for parts of something, "quartile" and "median" are [quantiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile), so the points that divide the data ranges into equal parts. So "half" is absolutely fine. You can say "data-points greater/lower then median" etc., but this is rather a discussion on English language rather then statistics.

Answer (score 6):

What could be better than half?

It's simple, completely unambiguous, and understood by all. Any effort to find a "better" word would likely just end up with jargonny gobbledygook that is more likely to obscure, rather than demonstrate, the value of your data description.